# jQuery: building a form dynamically from an array with a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a jQuery function that receives id of div element and json array

```
function FormBuilder(selector,myList){
    for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
        var rowHash = myList[i];
        if(rowHash['id'] > 0 ){
            $(selector).append('<form id="DialerInfo">');
            for (var key in rowHash) {
                $(selector).append(key +': <input type="text" name="' + key + '" value="' + rowHash[key] + '"><br/>');
            }
            $(selector).append('</form>');
        }
    }
}
```

And I expected this to build a proper form, i.e. all inputs should be between `<form>` and `</form>`  tags. But I'm receiving something completely  different:
First goes
`<form id="DialerInfo"></form>` 
then below all input fields. Why are they outside the form tags? does jQuery  close all tags automatically? how to prevent this behavior then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOM creation using jQuery doesn't work like string concatenation

You can create a form and append all the elements to it

```
function FormBuilder(selector, myList) {
  var $form = $('<form id="DialerInfo"></form>').appendTo(selector);
  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    var rowHash = myList[i];
    if (rowHash['id'] > 0) {
      for (var key in rowHash) {
        $form.append(key + ': <input type="text" name="' + key + '" value="' + rowHash[key] + '"><br/>');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//use

```
$.each(arrayorJSON,function(KEY,VALUE){
    //YOUR CODE HERE
})
```

//it is a jquery looper which accepts both array and json values and compatible with all browsers instead of for loop